# listview position id is not equal database keyinteger value

Tags: android

i want to delete listview selected position value from database but problem is listview  position only  give position id suppose if i give entries in database 1 3 4 5 2 6  when delete 2 it will delete 4 not 2 so tell me how to delete values from selecteing on listview help me im  confuse

```
   msglist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
          @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int position, long arg3) {

          DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MsgActivity.this);



                removeItemFromList(position); 
                  db.Delete_Contact(arg3);



          }
   });

             String CREATE_INBOX_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INBOX + "("
+ KEY_INBOXID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_MSG + " TEXT,"
+ KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";

   public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_INBOXID + " =? ",  new String[] { 
    String.valueOf(id) });
    Log.d("LOGInG VALUE2", "Value2: " + String.valueOf(id));
    db.close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete a row:

```
db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_INBOXID + " =?"+id,null);
```

You must set "position", not arg3

```
b.Delete_Contact(position);
```

Comment: but value of is is position id which is wrong not selected position crosponding database id

Comment: @user3332060 You must set "position", not arg3

Comment: i want to gell all row value of selected position from database

Comment: like this: delete from table_name where ID=5, if you have 5 row and theirs ID=5, all row will delete

Comment: please do test and debug

Answer (score 0):

When you populate the list view, in each item of your list view add a tag with the value of KEY_INBOXID,

```
listitemview.setTag(KEY_INBOXID_value);
```

Then the user clicks on the item, read the tag and use that to identify the record to delete.

```
msglist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
  // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the function
          @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int position, long arg3) {

          DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(MsgActivity.this);

                removeItemFromList(position); 
                  db.Delete_Contact(arg1.getTag());
          }
   });

             String CREATE_INBOX_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INBOX + "("
+ KEY_INBOXID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_MSG + " TEXT,"
+ KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";

   public void Delete_Contact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INBOX, KEY_INBOXID + " =" String.valueOf(id),  null);
    Log.d("LOGInG VALUE2", "Value2: " + String.valueOf(id));
    db.close();
 }
```

Comment: i do something like this  Cursor cursor = (Cursor) msglist.getItemAtPosition(position); but its not work help me

Comment: but in my senario not nessary listview contain numbers may b is text messages so what wioll i do then??

Comment: i want to get all values of listview selected position from database

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify. If you need more clarification edit your answer to include the code you use populate the listView.

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".